# Using Shiny to introduce graph filter

Tags: r, graph, filter, shiny, flexdashboard

Hello Stackoverflow Commununity !

I am working on a Dashboard using Flexdashboard and Shiny. 
I want to introduce a filter on a graph. 
The dataframe used for the graph is the following :

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2018/1/1"), by = "month")
date <- as.character(date[-1])
proto <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,
                            0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,
                            5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8), ncol = 3, nrow =   length(date), byrow = F))

names(proto)[1] <- "cap_1"
names(proto)[2] <- "cap_2"
names(proto)[3] <- "cap_3"
row.names(proto) <- date
proto$total <- proto[,1] + proto[,2] + proto[,3]
```

If I run the graph out of the shiny code, it works perfectly for each column and I obtain :

[Ggplot Graph for the total column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFpf8.png)

Now, I try to put this graph into my dashboard with the objective to have a filter on the graph to select the column (cap_1, cap_2, cap_3 or total) to plot.
Here is the code I used :

```
 ProtoUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fillCol(height = 600, flex = c(NA, 1), 
    inputPanel(
      selectInput(ns("cap"), "Capabilities:", choices = colnames(proto))
    ),
    plotOutput(ns("proto_plot"), height = "100%")
  )
}


Proto_serve <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$proto_plot <- renderPlot({
 ggplot(proto, aes(row.names(proto), input$cap, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size=1.5, color="blue") + 
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Number of prototypes", title = " ") +
  geom_rangeframe() +
  theme_tufte() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12), 
axis.title=element_text(size=13,face="bold"))
   })
}

ProtoUI("proto")
callModule(Proto_serve, "proto")
```

And I obtain this graph : 
[Graph in the dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J1kz.png)

Normally, the line must not be constant but should follow the data of the dataframe for the column selected.

Thanks for sharing your knowledge to solve my issue =)

Flavien.

Comment: Can you share the data using `dput` instead of sharing it as an image?

Comment: The data are now in my question ! Thanks =)